# Devise sign-up request method post using Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, postman

I created an only API rails project and added devise user model
now I am trying to sign-up using Postman but it does not save the new user on the
database
however, it does not return an error as well.

[Postman post request and parameters passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMrsN.png)

My app controller with the additional permitted attributes

```
`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = :name, { roles: [] }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end
end`
```

Devise User model with validations

```
    `class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :roles, presence: true

  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :vechiles, through: :group_entities
end`
```

The migration file for the devise user table

```
    class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Roles col. added to user table

```
    class AddRolesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :roles, :text, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

My Routes.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  resources :users, only: [:index]

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

Comment: Can you share `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: Postman is a useful debugging tool but a terrible workflow for testing software.  Instead of using Postman write an actual integration test with Minitest or RSpec. That will give you something which can be shared to show the exact steps taken to send the request and which can be repeated by others. As an added  bonus it will also safeguard against regressions.

Comment: I added the routes to the question.
I tried to create a user#create out of devise controller I was able to create a new user using Postman. But using the Devise route to sign up still has the same problem